# A few questions about implicit synchronization?

Tags: cuda

In the cuda programming guide, it is mentioned that the following operations will cause implicit synchronization:

> a page-locked host memory allocation

I'm wondering whether this include `cudaHostRegister` and `cudaHostUnregister`? If not then this shall imply that we can call `malloc` before all asynchronous operations, then in the asynchronous part we can do `cudaHostRegister`. Is this right?

> any CUDA command to the default stream

Does this include any operations with cudaEvent, such as recording events on stream 0 or let stream 0 wait some events in other streams?

By the way, does the implicit synchronization happen within one device or will the synchronization be over all the devices?

Comment: Are you asking this question in the context of a single stream or multiple streams?

Comment: It is with multiple streams.

Comment: One thing about cudaHostRegister() and cudaHostUnregister() - they are slow.  So whether or not they cause implicit synchronization (which I think they do), they are probably not what you want to be using, unless you need to pin pre-allocated memory such as shared memory and then just leave it registered.

Comment: @DavidSteinhauer: Thank you! This is very helpful! I indeed have something that slows down my program which I haven't figured out yet.

Comment: Have you tried using the profiler (nvvp, or NSight Eclipse Edition)?  That can be helpful for finding delays.

Comment: `cudaHostRegister()` is not designed to be called with any frequency. It uses operating system facilities to page-lock the specified address range, then has CUDA's kernel mode driver map that memory for the GPU. It likely is implicitly synchronous, and the time required to page-lock the address range varies with the platform and other circumstances (e.g., whether the pages are already resident).

Answer (score 1):

> I'm wondering whether this include cudaHostRegister and
>   cudaHostUnregister?

Yes, I believe there is implicit synchronization with these functions.  But like I said in my comment above, these are slow functions.  Use cudaHostAlloc() instead if you are able.  If you're using shared memory or something like that which requires cudaHostRegister(), you'd generally want to take care of this just once near the beginning of your program and then just leave it registered.

> Does this include any operations with cudaEvent, such as recording
>   events on stream 0 or let stream 0 wait some events in other streams?

Again, this is a CUDA call in the default stream, so I believe implicit synchronization is done here as well.

> By the way, does the implicit synchronization happen within one device
>   or will the synchronization be over all the devices?

Synchronization only applies to the same device.  It doesn't impact other devices.

Note that you can now create a stream which doesn't implicitly synchronize with the default stream using [cudaStreamCreateWithFlags](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__STREAM.html#group__CUDART__STREAM_1g2f3e3d8e9b3db7fffde77bdf67de7cf1):

```
cudaStreamCreateWithFlags( &stream, cudaStreamNonBlocking );
```

There is something else that could be useful if your host code runs CUDA kernels on the same GPU from multiple host threads.  CUDA 7.0 RC has a new nvcc option, --default-stream=per-thread, which you might want to look into.  With this option, each host thread by default uses its own stream.

But if you're trying to optimize and check for implicit synchronizations, I'd start by using the CUDA profiler, nvvp, or the profiler which is part of NSight Eclipse Edition.